# How do I use wildcard containing conditional pattern during sed substitution?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The following commands work.

```
sed -i "/BC_CD23.BC_B.BC_A1.N1_C/s/CELL4WL_4BL_3/CELL4WL_4BL_1/g" s1*M8*
sed -i "/BC_CD23.BC_B.BC_A1.N0_C/s/CELL4WL_4BL_3/CELL4WL_4BL_1/g" s1*M8*
```

This command doesn't work.

```
sed -i "/BC_CD23.BC_B.BC_A1.N*_C/s/CELL4WL_4BL_3/CELL4WL_4BL_1/g" s1*M8*
```

How do I use wildcards in patterns?

Comment: There is a difference between *wildcards* as used in file name matching/shell globbing and the much more powerful *regular expressions* as used in `sed` (or `grep` and others). You should perhaps read [an introduction](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks. I went through the link. I need to study regex in more detail .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use wild card in pattern

In your particular case, `N*` means *"match `N` char zero or more times"*.
If the pattern implies single `N` char and one(or more) following digits - that pattern part should be `N[0-9]\{1,\}`.
Besides, `.`(period) char matches any character, including newline (though newlines won't occur in the input here). To be matched literally it should be escaped `\.`
Thereupon, the *main* pattern would look as `/BC_CD23\.BC_B\.BC_A1\.N[0-9]\{1,\}_C/`

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Overview-of-basic-regular-expression-syntax

Comment: While your answer is perfectly correct and complete, I'm afraid that someone asking such a question has never heard of regular expressions and needs to be taught some basics to avoid being completely confused by this information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does "\{1,\}" mean in regex ?

Comment: @RoopakVasa, `\{i\}

    As *, but matches exactly i sequences (i is a decimal integer; for portability, keep it between 0 and 255 inclusive).
`

Comment: `\{4,7\}` is for minimum 4 times, maximum 7 times the expression before. You can leave away either value, so `\{,7\}` is between zero and seven times and, as in your question, `{1,\}` is one or more times. Some `sed` versions have the shortcut `\+` for that.